# UIScrollView does not work with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, subviews

I have a scrollview that is subview of view, and has the subviews. The problem is this: the scrollView came with the black background (as I have set transparent) and also does not work. The scrollView is connected with an `IBOutlet`. I redid the XIB 2 times, what needs fixing? When I add the scrollView as subview of view:

```
 [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

I get this error during runtime:

```
   0x132b61:  calll  0x132b66;   CA::Layer::ensure_transaction_recursively(CA::Transaction*) + 14
   EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2 address=0xbf7ffffc)
```

If I do not add it as a subview in the code, the view controller  opens and the scrollview is black and does not scroll.

Comment: What do you mean not working ? What exactly is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you init with your scrollView with frame:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 360)];
```

Remember also to set contentSize bigger than frame, for example:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2*280, 360);
```

Also add delegate in your interface:

```
<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

And delegate it:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably doing somewhere, something like:

```
[myScrollView addSubview:myAnotherView];
[myAnotherView addSubview:myScrollView];
```

which kicks an unwanted recursion. Check your code.

Comment: Not sure about the OP but I had my app crashing at CA::Layer::ensure_transaction_recursively and this fixed the problem for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I had a UIView that was receiving the same error. In my case I had forgotten to create an IBOutlet for my view. Once I did this, the error went away.